# How to do something like grep -B to select only one line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Everything is in the title. Basicaly let's say I have this pattern

```
some text lalala
another line 
much funny wow grep
```

I grep funny and I want my output to be "lalala"

Thank you

Comment: Just "lalala" or the whole line? Do you only want a line with "lalala" on it or whatever line happens to be two lines earlier (even if it doesn't contain "lalala"?

Comment: Yes just lala.
In my case it is an ip address. All I need to do is get the ip address which is 8 lines above at the end of the line of what I grep.
Kinda hard when you're not used to all the tools such as cut, sed, grep etc. I'm working on it but have a hard time with this one

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is to use either `ed` or `ex` to do this (it is trivial in them):

```
ed - yourfile <<< 'g/funny/.-2p'
```

(Or replace `ed` with `ex`.  You might have `red`, the restricted editor, too; it can't modify files.)  This looks for the pattern `/funny/` globally, and whenever it is found, prints the line 2 before the matching line (that's the `.-2p` part).  Or, if you want the most recent line containing 'lalala' before the line matching 'funny':

```
ed - yourfile <<< 'g/funny/?lalala?p'
```

The only problem is if you're trying to process standard input rather than a file; then you have to save the standard input to a file and process that file, which spoils the concurrency.

You can't do negative offsets in `sed` (though GNU `sed` allows you to do positive offsets, so you could use `sed -n '/lalala/,+2p' file` to get the 'lalala' to 'funny' lines (which isn't quite what you want) based on finding 'lalala', but you cannot find the 'lalala' lines based on finding 'funny').  Standard `sed` does not allow offsets at all.

If you need to print just the IP address found on a line 8 lines before the pattern-matching line, you need a slightly more involved `ed` script, but it is still doable:

```
ed - yourfile <<< 'g/funny/.-8s/.* //p'
```

This uses the same basic mechanism to find the right line, then runs a substitute command to remove everything up to the last space on the line and print the modified version.  Since there isn't a `w` command, it doesn't actually modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

Since `grep -B` only prints each full number of lines before the match, you'll have to pipe the output into something like grep or Awk.

```
grep -B 2 "funny" file|awk 'NR==1{print $NF; exit}'
```

You could also just use Awk.

```
awk -v s="funny" '/[[:space:]]lalala$/{n=NR+2; o=$NF}NR==n && $0~s{print o}' file
```

For the specific example of an IP address 8 lines before the match as mentioned in your comment:

```
awk -v s="funny" '
/[[:space:]][0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/ {
    n=NR+8
    ip=$NF
}
NR==n && $0~s {
    print ip
}' file
```

These Awk solutions first find the output field you might want, then print the output only if the word you want exists in the `n`th following line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at a slightly generalized Awk solution.  It maintains a circular queue of the last `q` lines and prints the line at the head of the queue when it sees a match.

```
#!/bin/sh
: ${q=8}
e=$1
shift
awk -v q="$q" -v e="$e" '{ m[(NR%q)+1] = $0 }
    $0 ~ e { print m[((NR+1)%q)+1] }' "${@--}"
```

Adapting to a different default (I set it to 8) or proper option handling (currently, you'd run it like `q=3 ./qgrep regex file`) as well as remembering (and hence printing) the entire line should be easy enough.

(I also didn't bother to make it work correctly if you see a match in the first `q`-1 lines. It will just print an empty line then.)